# How to create upload image and videos attribute in Admin product detail page in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, image-upload, product-video

I want to create image and video upload for in Admin Product page

Refer my screenshot:

[image]

Under **Available in** I have created a attribute aaa, Under aaa I should get images and videos upload like this.

Refer my screenshot:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve this.

Please someone guide me on this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can add video by uploading url key from vimeo.